# lwuit open default email/mail client from button

Tags: java, lwuit, nokia, nokia-s40, lwuit-button

Please tell me how do I open he default email client from a lwuit button?
and also predefine its subject and email address.

I know how to use buttons. I would appreciate code for email client. (cant find on internet)

using nokia s40 sdk from eclipse

Answer (score 1):

You can try this, using platform request and the mailto property.

[Opening apps from J2ME](http://www.developer.nokia.com/Resources/Library/Java/#!developers-guides/invoking-applications/invoking-applications-in-java-me.html)

[Example](http://www.developer.nokia.com/Commu...tformRequest%28%29)

My suggestion is, trying to send this e-mail via SMTP.

Take a look on this

[Send e-mail via SMTP](http://www.java-tips.org/java-me-tips/midp/sending-email-from-j2me-devices.html)